# Pdf not opening in new tab showing error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am trying to open pdf in new tab of browser but it showing error please help me.

```
public function show_pdf($fileName)
{
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize (realpath ( "assets\documents" ) . "\\" . $fileName) ); 
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;     
    filename=".realpath ( "assets\documents" ) . "\\" . $fileName);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    readfile(realpath ( "assets\documents" ) . "\\" . $fileName);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an app that does the same thing, the file is located somewhere on the server (unique file names) and im calling those with the filename

**In the view**

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>SomeControllerForFiles/someMethod/<?=$filename?>"></a>
```

**In the Controller**

```
function showThePDF($filename){
//if ur $filename contains the full path
//then $path = $filename
$path = '/THE/DIRECTORY/WHERE/FILE/EXIST/' . $filename;
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
    readfile($path);
}
```

So far works great.
In this case it's a on a linux server under apache, if u are using windows server u can get the files with paths like `DiscLetter:\\full_file_path.pdf`

if u keep the documents on the public_html folder u can access those with a link something like

`<a href="<?= base_url().'/documents_folder/'.$filename ?>">Let's see that file</a>`

In the last case, anyone could access it because it's on the public_html folder.

And, **important** regardless if u are allocating the files on the public_html folder or `/SOMEWHERE/IN/THE/SERVER` the path to the file on `readfile($path)` always needs to be the full path it should be like

**File somewhere in the server**

`/THIS/IS/THE_FOLDER/this_is_my_file.pdf`

`C:\\THIS\IS\THE\FOLDER\this_is_my_file.pdf`

**for link with files on the public_html folder**

`href = "http://this.is.my.page.com/assets/documents/this_is_my_file.pdf"`

Hope my answer helps u find the `$fullpath` :D